# Problems with SKAction.runBlock() in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

Here is some code of a simple SpriteKit game I am working on:

```
let square = SKShapeNode()
let square2 = SKShapeNode()

override func didMoveToView(view:SKView) {
    var moveSquare: SKAction
    moveSquare = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: someNumber, y:otherNumber), duration: NSTimeInterval(3))

    square.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveSquare1, SKAction.runBlock(checkIfSquareMatches(square)),SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
    square2.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),SKAction.runBlock(self.addChild(self.square2)) ,moveSquare, SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
}

func checkIfSquareMatches(shape:SKShapeNode) {...}
```

So I had two errors, one on the square.runAction line and the other on the square2.runAction line. The first says

"Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'dispatch_block_t' (aka '@convention(block) () -> ()')"

The second says the same as above, except instead of "type '()'" it says

"type 'Void' (aka '()')"

which I believe is the same thing because of the "(aka '()')".

Why am I getting these errors and how can I fix them? I saw a slightly similar post on stackoverflow about the problem of running a function in a SKAction.runBlock() but the solution stated the problem was that you cannot return a value in the runBlock, but my function does not return any value; it only changes the values of some variables, so I don't see the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you put snippets in the runBlock statement they need to be within curly braces {} unless they are a simple func call with no parameters

change it to

```
square.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveSquare1, SKAction.runBlock( { self.checkIfSquareMatches(self.square) } ),SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
square2.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),SKAction.runBlock( { self.addChild(self.square2 } )) ,moveSquare, SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
```

}

and the errors go away

Note you must reference variables using self. in runBlock calls

Comment: Thank you! This made the program work, however the squares still aren't getting added to the scene (the addchild(square2) doesn't seem to actually add the square). No more errors, but the code isn't doing what it is supposed to do. Any idea why?

Comment: By the way, I am fairly certain that it is in fact not being added because I turned on the node count and there aren't as many nodes as there should be if the addChild() worked. Also the SKShapeNode square (exact same properties as square2) from the first SKAction.runAction is added outside of the action, and it works perfectly fine, so nothing is wrong with the square.

Comment: you have square2 running an action

square2.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0),SKAction.runBlock( { self.addChild(self.square2 } )) ,moveSquare, SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
 but it's not added to the scene yet, so it can't run an action

. should be self.runAction

Comment: I changed it like you said, but it still isn't being added to the scene. It also now crashes after some time saying that I attempted to add a node that already has a parent (because those actions from above are part of another SKAction that repeats), so I tried adding another runBlock that removes the square from its parent after the moveSquare action, but it still crashes for the same reason. I think it is getting to the point where if I might just post a new question for this.

Comment: Never mind I think I've found out why this is happening. Thanks for the help!

Comment: i don't mean to question you but it was definitely what i said. I had changed it to self and it was adding.      self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0), SKAction.runBlock( {
            self.addChild(self.square2)
//            self.square2.runAction(moveSquare)
//            self.square2.removeFromParent()
        } )]))   
works